# How does critsend gather "Spam folder statistics with addresses"?

Tags: email, smtp, spam

Apologies if this is the wrong site - not really sure which site is best for this, but since it's SMTP-related (or is it?), I figured maybe this site had the best audience.

My company just set all of our live servers to route email through [Critsend](http://www.critsend.com) (at a cost). Apparently we've had some people complain about emails going missing, and this service lets us track it better...

I was pretty shocked, and said "There's nothing they can possibly tell us, that we can't get from the SMTP server logs!". However, I was given a huge list of features they support, including this:

> [Spam folder statistics with addresses](http://www.critsend.com/feature_analytics)

Apparently, they can tell us how many (and which!) emails went into spam folders.

I've done a little SMTP in my time, and I'm certain there is no way to get this information. So, what are they doing to claim this feature? (Note: Sadly, I don't have any access to actually see one of these reports).

Comment: Critsend is able to determine this, but it is proprietary.